# velocity (test instanceof)

Tags: velocity

How can I test the class of a given object in a velocity template. I can't find an instanceof directive

Answer (score 29):

There is no instanceof, but you can get class name as a string and then go from there:

```
${myObj.class.name} would return "com.test.MyObj"
${myObj.class.simpleName} would return "MyObj"
```

Comment: `class.name` works for me but not `class.simpleName`, for some reason.

Comment: This allows only to test the main class of the object, not one of its superclass or implemented interfaces. For that, you’ll need madmurdok’s solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can set this variable

```
    [VelocityValuesMap].put("TestClass", TestClass.class);
    [VelocityValuesMap].put("myObject", myObject);
```

and inside the velocity template you can do this

($TestClass.isAssignableFrom($myObj.getClass()))