# Check whether the given object is a list?

Tags: velocity

How can we check whether the given object is a list or other type
in velocity. In that list i have another list which i need to iterate again. 
 I also have another data in the parent list which i want to print while iterating parent list. But the problem is the child list object also get printing with actual data. So i want to print the data by checking whether its list or not. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Before you get any remarks on using too much logic in templates, try this reflection based approach :

[velocity (test instanceof)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087083/velocity-test-instanceof)